# Heroku double '/' problem - node js backend, 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, http-status-code-404

I have deployed my backend on heroku and I have a test get request's response on `/`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, World. The app is running!");
});
```

On hitting the `/` end point that is https://ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com/, I get the expected `GET` output.

But, when from the frontend react app, I hit any `POST` endpoint, e.g.:-

```
// index.js
app.use('api/portfolios/', (require('./routes/portfolio')));

// portfolio route
router.post('/getportfolios', async (req, res) => {...});
```

I am unable to get any response on the frontend.

As suggested by heroku docs, when I do `heroku logs`
I get the following error:-

```
2022-09-21T07:57:41.743176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="//api/portfolios/getportfolios" host=ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=0aff16a8-8aee-499e-a69e-4bdf8d583e6d fwd="103.164.24.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=204 bytes=312 protocol=https2022-09-21T07:57:41.808753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="//api/portfolios/getportfolios" host=ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=3c1974f2-522c-47b8-92d8-2f201bd0e2ab fwd="103.164.24.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=312 protocol=https2022-09-21T07:57:42.054955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="//api/portfolios/getportfolios" host=ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=6092ee53-d98d-4fa0-9fff-abd46554de56 fwd="103.164.24.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=445 protocol=https  
2022-09-21T07:57:42.172808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="//api/portfolios/getportfolios" host=ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=cbe7b873-b4f5-4eb6-a80f-12fd1018029a fwd="103.164.24.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=445 protocol=https
```

I don't know what is causing the following error. The app works perfectly fine on the local environment, but don't know why the problem has occured.

I am a beginner for heroku and I don't know much about it, also i searched the google and stackoverflow for the error but did not find any relevant solution to the problem.

I just assume that the error can be because of some double / `//` creating in the path as in the error it is shown e.g. `path='//api/portfolios/getportfolios'`. So, I also tried removing the / from frontend and everywhere else trying to make it sinbgle / but this didn't solve the problem.

Can someone please guide me to find the solution of the above problem.
Thank you!

////////////////EDIT////////////////
portfolio route file: [github](https://github.com/Ayush181005/Portfolio-Backend/blob/master/routes/portfolio.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
// index.js
const portfolioRoutes = require('./routes/portfolio');
app.use('/api/portfolios', portfolioRoutes);

// portfolio route
router.post('/getportfolios', async (req, res) => {...});
```

Comment: It fixed the double / problem but still getting the following error: `2022-09-21T09:55:02.999291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/portfolios/getportfolios" host=ayush-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=3da716f8-c574-486a-8282-c758db1db193 fwd="103.164.24.154" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=444 protocol=https`

Comment: you're currently getting 404, are you sure you typed the code snippet above correctly? can you show your whole `portfolio route` file?

Comment: Yes, its a big file so attaching github link to the edited question

Comment: And, the same code was working in local environment so, the links must be correct

Comment: is the index.js in your github the latest? if so, you're missing `/` before `api` in app.use

Comment: Yes i had removed the `/` as I thought it would remove the double `/` problem, I'll try adding it again